# Use of { } when importing libraries?

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, library, import, require

Can anybody tell me the exact use of { } in import/require library statements?

I've seen some other questions where people said it's to import just a part of a library, let's say the 'ethers' part of the 'harthat' library:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

Sounds good to me... But in the ethers documentation, they tell you for example to use:

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
```

But if we use the ethers library, isn't ethers the whole library?
I've tried it without the { } and for me it seems to work totally fine:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
```

So now I'm wondering, are the { } actually needed?

Why does the documentation say to use version 2 instead of version 3? Is there an actual difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

For ethers.js, the both `{ ethers }` and `ethers` work because during export, ethers also add a named export of itself.

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');

ethers.version // works
ethers.ethers.version // works
ethers.ethers.ethers.version // does not work
```

Ethers is exported inside ethers to prevent separate line for imports.

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');
const { providers } = require('ethers');

// since ethers is exported again, you can instead do
const { ethers, providers } = require('ethers');
```

In the case of hardhat, they have a wrapper library on top of ethers, which adds some hardhat-specific ethers utilities, in addition to exporting everything from ethers, so that users do not have to import ethers js again.

```js
const ethers = require('ethers');
const { getSigners } = require('hardhat-ethers');

// combine and access hardhat ethers utilities e.g. ethers.getSigners
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
```